# Jeffrey Way Laravel Generator doesn't work at all

Tags: php, laravel, sublimetext2

when I try to install jw laravel generator I must be doing something wrong because it doesn't respond.

- I have added Laravel 4 generator commands and these works fine
- I have installed Sublime Laravel Generator without problems
- I'm on windows so I copied laravelgenerator.sublime-settings to "package_dir/user/" because "users" file isn't there.
- I edited php path to C:/xampp/php

when I try to call "generate resource" command it does nothing.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you installed his generator through composer, like so:

Add package to composer.json:

```
"require-dev": {
    "way/generators": "2.*"
}
```

Update composer:

```
composer update --dev
```

Once that operation is complete you **must** add the **service provider** to the Laravel App Configuration. Like so:

Open the *app/config/app.php* file and add this new item to the providers array:

```
'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider'
```

That's it! Following those steps should make the generator work.

Run the `artisan` command to see the new `generate` commands.

Comment: OK thx now it almost works :D only thing that doesn't work is "generate:resource" command.

when I try to do this command it failes and in my sublime console I have this Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\sublime_plugin.py", line 270, in is_enabled_
  File ".\SymfonyCommander.py", line 302, in is_enabled
  File ".\SymfonyCommander.py", line 67, in loadSettings
AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'settings'

Comment: I think that is more related to the sublime text plugin, if you run the command in terminal/cmd.exe, does that work?

Comment: I have no experience with this plugin for Sublime. I make use of iTerm2 & ZSH. Which I definitely recommend if you are on a Mac.